# Find viscous friction for DC motor transfer function

Tags: control, motor, pid, microcontroller, dc

How do I find the viscous friction for my DC motor without measuring the input current and output torque.
I have to do a theoretical model on simulink and can't find any answers on how to find it

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Nick O. This looks like a homework question, and on stack exchange, questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve/understand the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving/understanding it. Please edit your question to add this information and take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. For advice on how to write a good question, see the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37).

Comment: What resources *do* you have?  Motor data sheet?  Anything else?  You ought to be able to find the total rotational losses from the motor current and RPM when it's running unloaded, but you won't know how much of that is viscous friction.